# iOS Share extension cannot load panorama image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios8-share-extension

When I am sending a panorama image (made with default panorama mode of my iPhone) to my iOS Share extension, `hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier` tells me that there is indeed an image sent, however `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` does not return anything.

I don't have any `completeRequestReturningItems` on the whole flow which could prevent the `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` to proceed until the end. This works however fine with a normal image.

How come panorama images give issues ?

```
    for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems)
    {
        for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments)
        {
            if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
            {
                NSLog(@"Found item:%@",item); --> Is displayed

                [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Item delivered"); --> Is never displayed for panorama pictures
                    if(image) {
                        selectedImage=image;
                        mediaType=1;
                        NSLog(@"Image found !!");
                        imageFound = YES;
                    }
                }];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try `[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeJPEG options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {...}];`

Comment: Just try `kUTTypeJPEG` in `loadItemForTypeIdentifier`. May be it will help you.